# C#, Context Object with Method that takes Interface to External DLL, Throws MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, dll

I have a service which acts as a scripting engine for normalization of content. The service extends its scripting language by dynamically loading DLLs at startup, passing a context object interface to a Load() method in each DLL. The context object provides the DLL with methods for Binding string names to factory objects, commands/functors, script object wrappers, etc.

I am having a problem where when the Load() method of one of the DLLs is called it throws a MissingMethodException if it attempts to call one of the binding methods. The method is one which takes an interface which is declared in another DLL, and I suspect something is going on with the method signature when passing the context object through Type.GetMethod.Invoke().

It should be noted that the exception is only thrown when *dynamically* loading the DLL via Assembly.LoadFile(). Referencing the DLL in the main process and using reflection to get the class/method, then dynamically invoking it from there causes no exception to be thrown.

---

*My code/project reference setup ...*

**Content.dll:**
  *References nothing*

```
public class ContentPackage { ... }

public interface IContentDataSource
{
    ContentPackage Receive();
    void Send(ContentPackage content);
}

public interface IContentDataSourceFactory
{
    IContentDataSource CreateInstance(string param);
    IEnumerable<IContentDataSource> CreateInstances(string param);
}

public class ContentXmlDataSource : IContentDataSource
{
    ContentPackage IContentDataSource.Receive() { ... }
    void IContentDataSource.Send(ContentPackage content) { ... }

    public class Factory : IContentDataSourceFactory
    {
        IContentDataSource IContentDataSourceFactory.CreateInstance(string param) { return new ContentXmlDataSource(param); }
        IEnumerable<IContentDataSource> IContentDataSourceFactory.CreateInstances(string param) { ... }
        IContentDataSourceFactory.CreateInstance(
        public static Factory Singleton { get { return s_Singleton; } }
        private static Factory m_Singleton = new Factory();
    }
}
```

**ExtensionInterface.dll:**
  *References Content.dll*

```
public interface IXmlTagCommand() { ... }

public interface IExtensionBindingContext
{
    void BindCommand(string name, IXmlTagCommand cmd);
    void BindDataSourceFactory(string name, IContentDataSourceFactory factory);
}
```

**Service.dll:**
  *References ExtensionInterface.dll, Content.dll*

```
public partial class TheService
{
    public class ExtensionBindingContext : IExtensionBindingContext
    {
        void IExtensionBindingContext.BindCommand(string name, IXmlTagCommand cmd)
        { ... }

        void BindDataSourceFactory(string name, IContentDataSourceFactory factory)
        { ... }

        ExtensionBindingContext(string basePath)
        {
            var paths = Directory.GetFiles(basePath, "*.dll");
            foreach (var path in paths)
            {
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(path);
                Type t = assembly.GetType("ExtensionLibrary");
                MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("Load",
                  BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

                method.Invoke(null, new object[] { this });  // Throws exception!
            }
        }
    }

    TheService()
    {
        (new ExtensionBindingContext()).LoadExtensions(".\DLLFolder\");
    }
}
```

**Extension.StandardContentFactories.dll:** (Loaded dynamically)
  *References ExtensionInterface.dll, Content.dll*

```
public class ExtensionLibrary
{
    public void Load(IExtensionBindingContext context)
    {
        context.BindCommand("SomeCommand", XTagCommands.SomeCommand); // Fine: No exception.
        context.BindDataSourceFactory("ContentXml", ContentXmlFactory.Singleton); // Causes whole function to throw exception if not commented out, preventing even the "BindCommand" call to not be reached.
    }
}
```

---

The exception specifics:

**Exception:**
*System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException, {"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."}*

**Inner Exception:**
*{"Method not found: 'Void SomeNamespace.ContentService.IExtensionBindingContext.BindDataSourceFactory(System.String, SomeNamespace.Content.IContentDataSourceFactory)'."}*

If I comment out the BindDataSourceFactory() line in StandardContentFactories.dll, the problem goes away. I am also successfully loading multiple other DLLs in this manner.

I've tried the following:
- Checking GAC folders for same named assemblies from project, none found
- Cleaning solution and rebuilding
- Verifying that all assemblies were using same .NET (4.0, not client profile)
- Passing the interface in a wrapper object instead, changing the method to take the wrapper: Field not found exception instead
- Passing the factory object as an "Object" (updating method parameters as well), then casting that object back into the interface that the factory object inherits: Invalid cast

Is there some kind of issue with passing objects behind interfaces to DLLs via dynamic assembly loading and invoking if that interface has a method that takes an interface which is defined in another referenced assembly? Are there possible work arounds to allow for this dynamic binding of factories from unknown DLLs if the interface issue is non-solvable?

**EDIT:**

After checking the modules as per mike z's suggestion, I see that their are two copies of each shared interface DLL being loaded (Content.dll and ExtensionInterface.dll); the first set of DLLs is being loaded from the service's host process bin\Debug directory; the second set of DLLs is being loaded from the bin\Debug directory of the first addon DLL that is loaded by Assembly.LoadFile().

The process uses an array of directory paths to search for addon DLLs in, and I was able to force the process to find/load the DLL that has the problem first, which caused the problem to go away. I'm guessing that all of the Assembly.LoadFile() loaded DLLs are using the set of shared interface DLLs that are loaded as a side effect of the first call to Assembly.LoadFile() (i.e. for the first addon DLL). When these DLLs load, maybe they are only including interface information for the IExtensionBindingContext.BindCommand() but not the IExtensionBindingContext.BindDataSourceFactory() and/or IContentDataSourceFactory since they are not used by that DLL.

Does anybody know if this assessment is correct? If so, is there a (standard or correct) way to force my Assembly.LoadFile() DLLs to correctly load ALL of the interface/method information from a shared library? (I'd rather not use contrived solutions like forcing the load order from a config file or creating a fake library that used all the features at the start.)

Comment: From the sound of it you possibly have two different versions of the same DLL loaded into different assembly binding contexts. I would run it in the debugger until I got the exception, then look at the Modules window, and go through each one of my assemblies and make sure it was loaded from where I thought it should be. Then if any were duplicated I would go inspect the time stamps (or even with a disassembler if I was really paranoid) to see if they were the same.

Comment: Thanks mike. I posted some notes on that at the bottom of my question. It looks like Assembly.LoadFile() keeps one instances of the DLLs and the main process another set. I expected each dynamically loaded DLL to use its own, local copies of the interface DLLs.